# How to use RegExp to match content between two specified strings?

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have a string `<div class="test">` and a string `var s = 5;</script></div></div>`

How do I match all content exactly between the two strings with RegExp in JavaScript?

input string:

```
.....<div class="test"><div class="inner-div"><script>var s = 5;</script></div></div>.....
```

expected output:

`<div class="inner-div"><script>var s = 5;</script>`

Thanks

Comment: What do you  mean by `match all content exactly between the two strings with RegExp in JavaScript`? Show us your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a string like this:

```
<div class="test">var s = 5;</div></div>
```

And you want: `var s = 5;`

then you could access the string with these regex:

```
var regex = new RegExp('(?!>)[^<>]+(?=<)','gm');
```

- `g` = global
- `m` = multiline

**edit after your edit:**

if you want to match something between two script tags:

```
var regex = new RegExp('(?!<script>)[^<>]+(?=<\/script>)','gm');
```